# I have a problem with output in C++, two last prints do not work

Tags: c++

My program compiles, but it just doesn't print anything after some point.

I tried changing the program and sometimes it printed "X="number"" and sometimes it didn't.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a;
  int b;
  int f;

  std::cout << "Type numbers a, b and f ";

  std::cout << std::endl << "a=";

  std::cin >> a;

  std::cout << std::endl << "b=";

  std::cin >> b;

  std::cout << std::endl << "f=";

  std::cin >> f;

  std::cout << std::endl
            << "Using the formula (а + b — f / а) + f * a * a — (a + b)"
            << std::endl;

  std::cout << "x=" << (a + b - f / a) + f * a * a - (a + b);

  return 0;
}
```

I expect two last `std::cout` to work, but they do not print anything.

Comment: It does print, just doesn't add a newline, so your prompt may overwrite this line. On what OS and in which shell are you running this?

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped with the last output.

Comment: I run it on cpp.sh .

Comment: buffer wasn't flushed oand environemnt didn't render it.  `endl`  does the flush.

Comment: `(a+b-f/(double)a)+f*a*a-(a+b)` to prevent integer division.

Comment: How do I flush after input?

Comment: @АлександрСахаров Enter key, of course! That's what it was designed for

Comment: [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) or [`std::fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) will take care of you. While your call to `cin` should trigger a flush of `cout`, that is an implementation designed feature that is not guaranteed. Instead `std::cout.flush();` after each output not ending in a newline.